# Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a + 2b + 3c = 26$ and $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 52$.

Tags: inequality

Find the largest possible value of $a$.

I used the Cauchy Schwarz inequality $(ax+by+cz)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$ as follows:

$a + 2b + 3c = 26$ is given; adding $a$ to both sides gives $2a + 2b + 3c = 26+a$. Then, we have $x = 2$, $y=2$, $z=3$. Putting this all into the inequality, we get:

$(ax+by+cz)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)(x^2+y^2+z^2)$

$(2a+2b+3c)^2 \leq (a^2+b^2+c^2)(2^2+2^2+3^2)$

$(26+a)^2 \leq (52)(17)$

$(26+a)^2 \leq 884$

$26 + a \leq \sqrt{884}$

$a \leq 2\sqrt{221} - 26 \approx 3.73$

However, the listed answer gives $a \leq \frac{26}{7} \approx 3.71$. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't have enough time, but if it is of any help, you haven't necessarily made a mistake. You might have (correctedly) followed a path that led you to a weaker result. Hopefully someone else will point out other ways.

Comment: Is the Cauchy Schwarz inequality guaranteed to be tight?  It doesn't seem that your conclusion is wrong (it doesn't contradict the given answer)...it's just not what the question was asking for.

Comment: Intersection of a plane and a sphere. Should be a circle. Then the point on the circle with largest $a$ coordinate.

Answer (score 2):

Knowing the answer, it is not hard to construct the right CS inequality to solve your problem:
$$52\cdot (13^2+12^2+18^2) \ge (13a+12b+18c)^2 = (7a+6\cdot 26)^2 \implies a \le \frac{26}7$$
It is easy to check equality is attained when $a = \frac{26}7, b = \frac{24}7, c = \frac{36}7$.

---

If you don't know the answer to start with, your method can be modified a bit to give the result.  We start with
$$52 \cdot \left(x^2+y^2+z^2 \right) \ge (x a + y b + z c)^2 \tag{1}$$

As the RHS needs to be of form $\left(\alpha a+\beta(a+2b+3c)\right)^2$ to isolate $a$, so we let $y = 2, z = 3$.  Thus we have

$$52 \cdot \left(x^2+4+9 \right) \ge \left(x a + 2 b + 3 c \right)^2 =\left((x-1) a + 26 \right)^2$$

Equality conditions give
$$\frac{a}x=\frac{b}2=\frac{c}3 \implies b = \frac{2a}x, c = \frac{3a}x$$
and the initial conditions give
$$a=26\frac{x}{x+13}, \quad a^2 = 52\frac{x^2}{x^2+13} \implies x = \frac{13}6, a=\frac{26}7$$

Comment: Note that OP is asking "What am I doing wrong", as opposed to "How do I solve this problem".

Comment: @CalvinLin think showing how to apply the method he chose correctly qualifies.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you are asked to find the least upper bound.

All that you have done is to find an upper bound. You still have yet to show that it is indeed the least upper bound.

In your CS inequality, in order for equality to hold, we must have

$$ \frac{a}{2} = \frac{b}{2} = \frac{ c}{3} , a = 2 \sqrt{221} - 26 $$

However, you can check that the initial conditions would not hold.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve $a + 2b + 3c = 26$ for $b$ and plug into $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 = 52$ which gives:

$$13c^2+6ac-156c+5a^2-52a+676=208 \tag{A}$$

Which is a conic section (ellipse) and the maximum can be found by taking a derivative wrt $c$:

$$26c + 6a + 6c\frac{da}{dc} - 156 + 10a\frac{da}{dc} - 52\frac{da}{dc} = 0$$

and setting $\frac{da}{dc} = 0$ :

$$26c + 6a - 156 = 0 \tag{B}$$

Solving **(B)** for $c$ and plugging into **(A)** gives:

$$a = \frac{27}6$$

as the max.

Comment: Note that OP is asking "What am I doing wrong", as opposed to "How do I solve this problem".

Comment: @CalvinLin I agree, and I am not familiar enough with CS inequality to comment too much on that, but I believe a good first step in figuring out what you are doing wrong is to verify what the correct solution would be.  And logically, he did nothing wrong (AFAIK), he just didn't answer the question.

Comment: My solution answered his question. I'm wondering why the other solutions (posted after mine) are ignoring the actual question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Our conditions give
$$a^2+b^2+\left(\frac{26-a-2b}{3}\right)^2=52$$ or
$$13b^2-2(52-2a)b+10a^2-52a+208=0.$$
Hence, $$(52-2a)^2-13(10a^2-52a+208)\geq0$$ or
$$a(26-7a)\geq0$$ or
$$0\leq a\leq\frac{26}{7}.$$
For $a=\frac{26}{7}$ we obtain $b=\frac{52-2\cdot\frac{26}{7}}{13}=\frac{20}{7}$ and $c=\frac{26-\frac{26}{7}-2\cdot\frac{20}{7}}{3}>0,$

which says that the answer is $\frac{26}{7}$.

Done!